# Dynamic range into standard deviation formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, range, standard-deviation, iif-function

I need to calculate the standard deviation of returns in excel. I have monthly returns for a group of companies; lets say for company A, I have months 1 to 12 in 1995 and 1996 but for 1997 only months 1 to 7. I have a group of 2000 companies, they are all in the same column, and I dont know how to standardize a formula where the range changes depending on the number of months I have for that year.

Comment: They say a picture is worth a thousand words.  Please show how your data is structured with expected outcome.

Comment: You could use a Table with structured references; you could use a dynamic named range; please show what you have tried and where you have run into a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The range passed to `STDEV` can contain empty values (i.e., months 8 to 12 of 1997), which are ignored in the calculation of the standard deviation. I don't know how the rows/columns are ordered exactly, but perhaps it would be possible to use the same formula for 1995, 1996 and 1997?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INDEX` function for getting a dynamic range.  For example, say you have a range with 2 columns and 10 rows (This should be easy enough to use formulas, like `COUNTA`, to find out)

```
=STDEV(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,1,4)&":"&ADDRESS(COUNTA(A:A),COUNTA(1:1),4)))
```

Explanation:

- `ADDRESS(Row number, Column number, Reference type)`: Here I have 4 as reference type which means "relative".  You can check Excel Help to see what else they have.
- `ADDRESS()&":"&ADDRESS()`: This will give me a range from A2:B10. There are other ways such as OFFSET to retrieve this value.
- `INDIRECT(Reference text)`: From the above range A2:B10, it is a string that Excel doesn't understand so using INDIRECT will translate that string into a real range.

You can test this formula first before entering into Name Manager or define a range name.  Hope this helps.

Comment: `You can use INDEX function`. I see no use of `INDEX` which would be better than the use of so many Volatile functions. `=STDEV(INDEX(A:A,2):INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)-1))`

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  INDEX is a better way to do.  Those volatile functions will slow things down if you have many.